# Oracle Is there a way to update date and not month, year

Tags: oracle, date

Is there a way to update the date part of a column of type Date. For example, a row in the DB has value 2013-11-22 [stored in YYYY-MM-DD format]. And I want to update it to 2013-11-01.

If it had been one or few rows I could have done a simple update. But the real problem is that there are about hundred thousand rows with different date values. And I want to update all the dates to the 1st of each month. For example

```
     Actual    What I would like it to be
    2013-01-22  2013-01-01
    1989-10-03  1989-10-01
    2004-07-01  2004-07-01
    2005-12-31  2005-12-01
```

Would appreciate any help, how can i get this done through SQL. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the data type is a date, use [trunc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm)

```
TRUNC(date_column, 'mm')
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7681/1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the trunc() function.

For example:

> UPDATE thetable set datevalue =  trunc(datevalue, 'MM');

Comment: for efficiency, ... where datevalue > trunc(datevalue, 'MM')